# Regularity of maps in algebraic topology for manifolds

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a $n$ manifold such that $\pi_k(M)$ is non trivial. What can we expect about the regularity of a representant $f:S^k\rightarrow M$ of a non-trivial cycle? For example, if $M$ is a manifold of class $p$, is it possible to find a $C^p$ function? I heard that these kind of problems were studied by the Russian school some decades ago, so I am mostly asking for a reference, but I would also like to know if there existed an answer to this specific question.

Comment: For the $C^\infty$ and $C^\omega$ cases this has been answered in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/203627/is-the-analytic-version-of-the-whitney-approximation-theorem-true

Comment: Thank you very much ThiKu, but if $p$ is a finite positive integer, and the manifold is no more than $C^p$, the question still needs an answer. But I will check in details Whitney's result; it would not be too surprising if his proof could be adaptable to lower regularity. Of course, if there is a direct reference, I would really appreciate the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've often heard it quoted as a Corollary of this paper that every homotopy class $\alpha: S^k\to M$ is represented by a map with only fold singularities (of type $\Sigma^{1,0}$):

Èliašberg, Ja. M.
Singularities of folding type. (Russian) 
Izv. Akad. Nauk SSSR Ser. Mat. 34 1970 1110–1126.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Grant, I will close the question if a get an answer about low regularity manifolds.

Comment: You're welcome @Paul-Benjamin. There's no need to close the question (you can accept an answer, but in my opinion people are often too quick to do this as it discourages other would-be answerers).

Comment: Thank you for your understanding, it is what I thought too.